# Best cordova sqlite plugin?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

In cordova's docs, I see 3 sqlite plugins mentioned:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html

I see various issues in each of those in github, but what's the reason for the existence of 3 separate projects and what are the strengths/weaknesses of each?

Answer (score 0):

The first one is the oldest and most used.
The second one allows you to include a pre-populated database in your app.
I think the last one is the newest with performance improvements.